# How does numba infer the types of literally initialized locals?

Tags: python, numba

Numba does something cool and surprising:

```
@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def sum(arr):
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        result += arr[i]
    return result
```

When called with an int64 array, it returns an int. When called with a float64, it returns a float.

This is suprising since, result is initialized with a literal integer 0 -- which I assumed it would determine the type of result. Why isn't the result always an int?

Here's when `sum.inspecttypes()` says for the float64 array case:

```
================================================================================
sum (readonly array(float64, 1d, C),)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# File: /home/.../fast_ops.py
# --- LINE 164 --- 
# label 0
#   del $const0.1

@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)

# --- LINE 165 --- 

def sum(arr):

    # --- LINE 166 --- 
    #   arr = arg(0, name=arr)  :: readonly array(float64, 1d, C)
    #   $const0.1 = const(int, 0)  :: int64
    #   result = $const0.1  :: float64
    #   jump 6
    # label 6

    result = 0
```

Comment: Presumably because adding a float and an int will normally produce a float

Comment: Yes -- but statically typed worlds a+=b usually leaves a the same type it was before.

Comment: Python isn't statically typed

Comment: Numba compiles to statically typed intermediate code.

Comment: In fact, in this example, result *is* statically typed. Its a int in the version of the function when  arr is an int array, and a float in the separate function when arr is an float array. Inside the function, its only one type, for the whole function.

Comment: result is initialized with a literal integer 0 _in python_. In python that does not and should not coerce the return value to a certain type, so numba ensures that the same contract holds true in its produced code

Comment: According to sum.inspect_types, result is a float64 when its initialized to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a high level description - see docs [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/proposals/type-inference.html#numba-type-semantic).  Here's a retelling based on my (limited!) understanding of that.

In numba's compilation process there is a type unification process/solver to convert everything to efficient low level ops.  This can produce multiple verions of the function depending on the inputs.

In your function, a constraint is that this line - `result` and `arr[i]` *must* be the same type.

```
result += arr[i]
```

Absent an input, `result` would be an integer.  but in the context of `arr` being a double, the only lossless way to unify types is casting `result` to a double.  If you went the other way, converting `arr` to an int, you'd destroy information.